# Creating an HTML table with BASH & AWK

Tags: html, bash, function, awk, html-table

I am having issues creating a html table to display stats from a text file. I am sure there are 100 ways to do this better but here it is:

**(The comments in the following script show the outputs)**

```
#!/bin/bash

function getapistats () {
    curl -s http://api.example.com/stats > api-stats.txt
    awk {'print $1'} api-stats.txt > api-stats-int.txt
    awk {'print $2'} api-stats.txt > api-stats-fqdm.txt
}

# api-stats.txt example
#    992 cdn.example.com
#    227 static.foo.com
#    225 imgcdn.bar.com
# end api-stats.txt example

function get_int () {

    for i in `cat api-stats-int.txt`;
        do echo -e "<tr><td>${i}</td>";
    done
}

function get_fqdn () {

    for f in `cat api-stats-fqdn.txt`;
        do echo -e "<td>${f}</td></tr>";
    done

}

function build_table () {

echo "<table>";
echo -e "`get_int`" "`get_fqdn`";
#echo -e "`get_fqdn`";
echo "</table>";
}

getapistats;

build_table > api-stats.html;

# Output fail :|
# <table>
# <tr><td>992</td>
# <tr><td>227</td>
# <tr><td>225</td><td>cdn.example.com</td></tr>
# <td>static.foo.com</td></tr>
# <td>imgcdn.bar.com</td></tr>

# Desired output:
# <tr><td>992</td><td>cdn.example.com</td></tr>
# ...
```

Comment: The single quotes go outside the curly braces. I know it works like that, but at the next simple increment in complexity it fails. Don't use `for i in $(cat)` - use `while read -r; do ...; done < filename`. Use `$()` instead of backticks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is reasonably simple to do in pure awk:

```
curl -s http://api.example.com/stats > api-stats.txt
awk 'BEGIN { print "<table>" }
     { print "<tr><td>" $1 "</td><td>" $2 "</td></tr>" }
     END   { print "</table>" }' api-stats.txt > api-stats.html
```

Awk is really made for this type of use.

Comment: You can pipe the output of this directly to a browser using [bcat](https://rtomayko.github.io/bcat/) or [this little script](https://gist.github.com/HeinrichHartmann/5ab1a4396e264f507e78333c210e9c1c) on OSX

Comment: Shouldn't the last `<tr>` be `<\tr>' instead?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with one awk at least.

```
curl -s http://api.example.com/stats | awk '
    BEGIN{print "<table>"} 
    {printf("<tr><td>%d</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n",$1,$2)}
    END{print "</table>"}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done w/ bash ;)

```
    while read -u 3 a && read -u 4 b;do
      echo $a$b;
    done 3</etc/passwd 4</etc/services
```

but my experience is that usually it's a bad thing to do things like this in bash/awk/etc

the feature i used in the code is **deeply** burried in the bash manual page...

i would recommend to use some real language for this kind of data processing for example: (ruby or python) because they are more flexible/readable/maintainable

Comment: yeah `python` might be the way to.  Thanks bud ;)