# How to take bash command output which is in tabular form, in html tabular format

Tags: bash, shell

Bash command output is shown as a table but not able to extract column as they are in the output instead of that each word is acting as a field, if in the shown output column two words are there both of these words i am getting as two fields even though these two are one of the cell value of column.

```
$disk status
Disk States   tiers
In Use        10
Spare         2
Available     13
TOTAL DISKS   25
```

here TOTAL DISKS is in Ist column but I am using awk and taking $1(first field) it is giving TOTAL, but I want TOTAL DISKS. how to do this, I am not getting it?

Comment: To get the last field on the line in awk, use `$NF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are interesed in the last column, here are 2 ways to achieve it:

1. instruct `awk` to return the last column

   `$ disk status | awk '{print $NF}'`
2. revese the column order (last column will become the first), return the first column and then reverse it back

   `$ disk status | rev | awk '{print $1}' | rev`

Answer (score 0):

The reason AWK only shows the first word is that it by default separates fields/columns by any white space including the space in "TOTAL DISKS" making some of your rows 3 columns and some 2.

Either use `FIELDWIDTHS` to set (GNU) AWK to use fixed column width input, for your example :

```
$ disk status | awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="14 6" '{print $1}'
```

or force 2 columns by prepending `NF==3{$1=$1" "$2; $2=$3}` to your AWK (merges first 2 columns if there are 3) :

```
$ disk status | awk 'NF==3{$1=$1" "$2; $2=$3} {print $1}'
```

You can also try simply changing your field separator (-F) to a tab `-F $'\t'` or more than one single white space (in this case 2 spaces) :

```
$ disk status | awk -F'  ' '{print $1}'
```

Either way, $1 and $2 are now your 2 columns.

Your title suggest you also want HTML table output. This is described in [Creating an HTML table with BASH & AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486756/) . Based on that you could use :

```
$ disk status | awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="14 6" 'BEGIN { print "<table>" } {print "<tr><td>" $1 "</td><td>" $2 "</td></tr>" } END { print "</table>" }'
```